# How to deal with Camel Case for Eclipse Templates?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

I'm trying to write an Eclipse template which will create getters and setters when I create an attribute.  My current template works, except for the camel casing for the getters and setters.

> private ${type} ${field};
>
> private ${type} get${field}() {return ${field};}
>
> private void set${field}(${type} ${field}) {this.${field} = ${field};}

Any tricks to do so?  I am aware that Eclipse can generate the getters and setters for me, but #1: it's menu driven (slow), #2: it's not in the format I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best you can do right now is

```
private ${Type} ${field};

private ${Type} get${Field}() {return ${field};}

private void set${Field}(${Type} ${field}) {this.${field} = ${field};}
```

This defines separate linked variables for the upper and lower case names.

You may be able to define a VariableResolver in a custom plugin to do this

Answer (score 7):

Nope, it's not possible to do it straight up using Eclipse.  It's actually logged as a bug:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=220953

but you should be able to add a custom extension to allow this, but you'll need to learn about the Eclipse framework and plugins in order to do that.