# Change Eclipse Getters Setters syntax

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible to make eclipse generate GetVar1() instead of getVar1() ? (with capital G)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825457/how-to-deal-with-camel-case-for-eclipse-templates

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I very much doubt it, since that breaks both normal Java naming conventions for methods and the JavaBeans properties rules.

I would *strongly, strongly* recommend that you abide by Java naming conventions. Why would you want to make your code look inconsistent with all the other Java libraries including the standard library?

Comment: Not to mention the way this would make his code incompatible with all sorts of things which use reflection and depend on the JavaBeans rules.

Comment: I will stick with java naming conventions! thanks it's very appreciated!

Comment: The first example of needing properly named getters and setters that comes to mind is serialization.

Comment: @Brian XMLEncoder/XMLDecoder require well-formed setters and getters, but ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream do not.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because Eclipse follows Java naming conventions for generating getters and setters.