# Generating setter/getter in Eclipse with following format: get0(), get1(), set0(

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Is there a possibility to let Eclipse generate getter/setter in this form:

```
public int a;
public int b;

public get0(){return a;}
public get1(){return b;}
public set0(int val){a = val;}
```

etc. ?

Comment: Why do you need this kind of code?

Comment: even if the IDE does have this feature, it's probably harder to use than manual editing :)

Comment: Srsly Aakash, don't ask :D Coding convention for the project .... :/
In IntelliJ it's pretty easy as far as I know. That's why I've asked - manual editing won't be quicker, for sure :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Eclipse Getters Setters syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579892/change-eclipse-getters-setters-syntax)

Comment: You are right. Kinda the same direction

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, there is an option to automatically generate Getters and Setters for all instance-fields you have in your class (or you can select the ones that you want, whatever). You'll want to go to the `Source` tab, and scroll down to `Generate Getters and Setters...`. From there, you should be able to choose which ones you want to generate.
As for actually calling them something other than the name of the variable, Eclipse doesn't really provide you with much. It may be better to do it manually, or even to make your own code generator, if you really want to.

### Edit

You can go and fiddle with the `Code Template`, as shown at the bottom of the `Generate Getters and Setters` popup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but of course I already use the automatically generate getter/setter but the question was in special about setting up the naming

Comment: @ ur Edit: Does not provide the functionality I'm looking for. I need to specify the setter/getter names. Not the "code content"

Answer (score 0):

Right click where you want your getters -> source -> Generate Getters and Setters. Now `only` select the the getters option. It will populate all your getters. Then repeat this for the setters below your getters. Then you will have the format you want.

Comment: I think you didn't got what I want. It's not about the order. It's about the indexed naming

Comment: Okay, that is not very clear from the post. It can be taken in either way.