# Strange autogenerated getter and setter in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I use the auto generation for getter/setter in Eclipse for an class field with a name like
`String lAttr` it will produce this:

```
public String getlAttr() {
  return lAttr;
}
public void setlAttr(String lAttr) {
  this.lAttr = lAttr;
}
```

The first letter of the field will not be capitalized! But some frameworks which I use, work with reflection and invoke the getter/setter by using the "get" + capitalized field name.

Can I change the code generation for getter/setter in eclipse to produce an output like `getLAttr()` and `setLAttr()` ?

Comment: This sounds like a bug with eclipse.

Comment: It seem to only happen when there is only 1 lower case character in the prefix.

Comment: Eclipse makes the getter and setter names according to the Java conventions, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991316/where-is-the-javabean-property-naming-convention-defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I don't think it's possible, similar discussion:

[Change Eclipse Getters Setters syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579892/change-eclipse-getters-setters-syntax)

2) another option, as alternative, is to use templates for getters and setters. though there is a small problem there too, similar discussion:

[How to deal with Camel Case for Eclipse Templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825457/how-to-deal-with-camel-case-for-eclipse-templates)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to give your own names of getter/setter in eclipse.
Make your variable private. Go to error where you are trying to access private variable in another class.
Select the quick fix of generating getter/setter. It pops up a dialog where getter/setter names are modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse are you using? I tried this in Eclipse 3.5.2, and when I moused-over the field and clicked "create getter and setter for 'lAttr'", the dialog box that appeared allowed me to change the generated names, in this case from `getlAttr` to `getLAttr` and `setlAttr` to `setLAttr`. Another option would be to just name your field `LAttr` from the start and avoid the whole mess.

Comment: A field starting with capital is breaking Java conventions.