# Struts2 passing variables case

Tags: struts2, datatables, ognl

I'm using Datatables server side ajax pagination and need to pass some variables to server.
My server is running Struts2 actions to handle this datatables requests.

I'm facing some problems because datatables is passing predefined internal variables (like iDisplayStart, iDisplayLength, iColumns, sSearch), but Struts2 cannot receive this kind of camelcase style (just first one char lower and second upper case).

To ensure this, I created this test action:

```java
@Action (value = "dummy", 
    results = { 
        @Result(name="ok", type="httpheader", params={"status", "200"}) } 
    ) 

@ParentPackage("default")
public class DummyAction {
    private String xTrace;

    public String execute () {
        System.out.println( xTrace );
        return "ok";
    }

    public String getxTrace() {
        return xTrace;
    }

    public void setxTrace(String xTrace) {
        this.xTrace = xTrace;
    }

}
```

I'm calling this URL:

```
localhost:8580/sagitarii/dummy?xTrace=thisisatest
```

The output is NULL, but when I change xTrace to xyTrace (and get, set and url too) all goes fine.
How can I make this to work?

*** EDIT ***

I already tried with any word with this format: iPad, iMac, iPhone, eMail, ...
I think this could be just my configuration, but please give a try before post answers.

Comment: @AndreaLigios is right. Change your getters/setters to `getXTrace`/`setXTrace` and it will work.

Comment: My getters and setters was generated by eclipse. Give my code above a try.

Comment: Of course this will work. Algorithm to construct setter is very simple: put prefix `set`, turn first letter of parameter to upper case and voila. So for `xTrace` parameter S2 will search `setXTrace` method.

Comment: I know man. Just give a try. Make a setter using Eclipse's GGAS for "iPad" and other for "imPad".

Comment: This is the eclipses algorithm for "sEcho": `getsEcho()` and for "stEcho": `setStEcho(String stEcho)`. By follow this, "stEcho" work and "sEcho" do not work.

Comment: Ok, yes it is more complicated than that. But what do you want? Like I already said @AndreaLigios answer is right.

Comment: I want to create a variable with just first char lower and second upper and make it to work with predefined getters and setters.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7264253/1700321.

Comment: Predefined by eclipse? And what happens when you move to some other ide say... notepad. What will happen then?

Comment: Yes. After variable declaration, I just press CTRL+3 and type GGAS (Generate Getters And Setters) and Eclipse do the rest. All getters and setters generated by eclipse follow the specification so I don't know what will happen in Struts if I change the setter "by hand". See my own answer. I'm already solved this by using a fast and safe method. Cold Case.

Comment: *by hand*? Setters/getters are no magic stuff there are just methods. *what will happen* - it will work as expected. *fast and safe method* - it isn't fast, and save compared to what? Writing code by hand?

Comment: You're right. It works. I was without time to come back to this code and change it. If @AndreaLigios undelete his post I'll aprove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but Struts2 cannot receive this kind of camelcase style (just first one char lower and second upper case)

This is actually *not true*. Struts2 can receive any variable name that comply JavaBeans spec. But apart from the Java implementation of [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/spec-136004.html) spec. (if you want to learn more about JavaBeans, see this post [What is a JavaBean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3295496/573032)), it's using its own implementation. Because Struts2 uses OGNL to access bean's properties you should know what a "property" is according OGNL language.

> What is a property? Roughly, an OGNL property is the same as a bean property, which means that a pair of get/set methods, or alternatively a field, defines a property (the full story is a bit more complicated, since properties differ for different kinds of objects; see below for a full explanation).

And the full explanation you can find here: [Referring to Properties](http://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Referring_to_Properties).

I will not dig into details how OGNL treats properties of the object but it should follow the contract for [`PropertyAccessor`](http://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-ognl/apidocs/org/apache/commons/ognl/PropertyAccessor.html). There's a lot of implementations for different kind of "properties".  The one that OGNL uses for objects is `ObjectPropertyAccessor`. Here's a merely description what it does:

> Implementation of `PropertyAccessor` that uses reflection on the target object's class to find a field or a pair of set/get methods with the given property name.

How it's doing it you can find via browsing the source code. I'll just say that it's capitalizing the the first letter of the property name before using it with `get/set` method prefix. So, you have asked

> How can I make this to work?

Change the method signature of the getter/setter for properties

```java
public String getXTrace() {
    return xTrace;
}

public void setXTrace(String xTrace) {
    this.xTrace = xTrace;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Since OGNL 3.0.11 the single lowercase letter is not uppercased.

Comment: Sorry Roman. You're correct too, but @Andrea Ligios wrote first (his answer was deleted and then restored). Thanks for detailed explanation (as usual) although I did not understand much. The real problem was in Eclipse method generator I trust too much.

Comment: @MagnoC This is not a question who answered the question first, or second, or later. Before making  decision you should look at the quality of the post  and if the answer helped you to solve your problem. I've found your question an interesting discussion about JavaBeans convention and it's my problem that I couldn't explain it better.

Comment: Agree. @Andrea Ligios solved my problem. I think your answer leads to root of question `why should I follow the naming specs?` or `how this work in deep?`but the real problem was my mistake in trust Eclipse method name generation since if I code using a text editor I would have written correctly. Andrea Ligios simply said: `you dumb! pay attention what you're doing`.

Comment: The problem was that Eclipse's generation is *correct* and it's *not your mistake*, but it's not working with Struts. Andrea's answer was correct, but he didn't explain anything about it. And I thought that questions you have implied discussing his answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the variable is

```java
private String xTrace;
```

getters and setters should be

```java
public String getXTrace() {
    return xTrace;
}

public void setXTrace(String xTrace) {
    this.xTrace = xTrace;
}
```

regardless of the double consecutive uppercase characters. The rule is that the first character after the set / get part is uppercased, the rest is unchanged

Comment: I think you not understood my problem. Setters and getters are correct (I always use eclipse shortcuts). This will return null. Try yourself. Any variable with this format <firstlower><secondupper> will return null (iPad, iMac, eMail,...).

Comment: As promissed. This is the correct solution. I always use the Eclipse `GGAS` shortcut and wait it to be always correct. By generating getters and setters using this shortcut and then changing it "by hand" (or to be less lazy, bypassing Eclipse shortcuts and write all methods) Struts will work as spected.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out by retrieving the variables using HttpServletRequest and bypassing struts way.

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)ActionContext.getContext().get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
xTrace = req.getParameter("xTrace");
```

This will get variables correctly.

**EDIT**

Better and elegant way:

As commented by Aleksandr M, changing the two consecutives setter name to uppercase makes struts sets the data correctly.

Comment: Upvoted for using constant. :) Just a note: you can also use `ServletRequestAware` to get `HttpServletRequest`.