# Why can't I get json from struts 2 action?

Tags: jquery, struts2, ognl, struts2-json-plugin

I want to send ajax post request to my struts action using jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ds/query",     
        data :JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType:"json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success : function(d, t, x){
            console.log(x);
        }
    });
```

my action configuaration:

```
<package name="ds" namespace="/ds" extends="json-default">
        <action name="query" class="gov.cbrc.gzbanking.action.DataServiceAction" method="query">
            <interceptor-ref name="json">
                <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <result type="json">
                <param name="noCache">true</param>
                <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
                <param name="root">qRes</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

my action class :

```
public class DataServiceAction {

    private QueryRequest qReq;

    private QueryResponse qRes;

    public QueryRequest getQr() {
        return qReq;
    }

    public void setQr(QueryRequest qReq) {
        this.qReq = qReq;
    }

    public QueryResponse getqRes() {
        return qRes;
    }

    public void setqRes(QueryResponse qRes) {
        this.qRes = qRes;
    }

    public String query() throws Exception{
        App.getLogger().debug(qReq.toString());
        String dsClz = SysCodes.getCodeItem("data_service", qReq.getDs()).getConfig1();
        Class<?> dsCls = Class.forName(dsClz);
        if(!DataService.class.isAssignableFrom(dsCls)){
            throw new Exception("specified class does't implement DataService interface.");
        }else{
            DataService ds = (DataService) dsCls.newInstance();
            System.out.println(JsonUtil.toJson(ds.query(qReq)));
            qRes = ds.query(qReq);
        }
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

QueryRequest and QueryResponse are just java beans, when I execute my code, Server can read json data and do it's job without error, **and I am sure QueryResponse object is popluted with data.** but I can't get anything at client side, responseText and responseJson are both null.

why did not struts-json plugin convert my QueryResponse  object into json string automaticaly?

my QueryResponse  class :

```
public class QueryResponse {

    private int total;

    private List<?> data;

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public List<?> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<?> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


}
```

the actual type of data list contains must be determined at runtime, for example, if data contains list of Role objects:
package gov.cbrc.gzbanking.domain;

```
public class Role {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String remark;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

then expected result is like this:

```
{
total : "1", data :[{"id":"admin", "name":"admin role"}]
}
```

Comment: You are using only one interceptor for you action. Use default stack + json interceptor.

Comment: R u using Struts 2 JSON Plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using Struts2. Struts2 is used to capitalize property name to resolve a getter method, before a "get" method name could be resolved a property `"qRes"` capitalized to `"QRes"` and prefixed with "get". So, the method name will be `getQRes`.  You can remove `root` parameter from the result and see if it can be used otherwise, or rename a getter method name as

```
public QueryResponse getQRes() {
    return qRes;
}
```

You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27928219/573032) question about why generated getters and setters in Eclipse don't work with Struts2 OGNL.

Comment: I am now using Gson to serialize objects to json. but I will give it a test later  on what you said, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not reading data properly at client side. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ds/query",     
    data :JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType:"json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success : function(d, t, x){
        console.log(t);
        console.log(d[0].id);
        console.log(d[0].name);
    }
});
```