# Struts 2: Incorrect/misspelled getter and setter name of a field

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

I have declared a boolean variable as `isABooleanValue` in the Struts 2 modelbean and I am able to see the value by using this `modelbean.aBooleanValue` in jsp.

getter looks like this

```
public boolean isABooleanValue(){
     return isABooleanValue;
}
```

setter looks like this

```
public void setABooleanValue(boolean isABooleanValue){
     this.isABooleanValue=isABooleanValue;
}
```

Jsp code

`<s:property value="modelbean.aBooleanValue" />`

can anyone explain how an incorrect variable name be accessed like this from value stack.

**Edit**

Solution

Using property in JSP is based on the Getter method specified. `modelbean.aBooleanValue` calls the `isABooleanValue()` method defined in your Model Bean, hence, not dependent on private field name.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27928219/5086633)

Update:-
Though this may seem to work in older version of OGNL but OGNL version 3.0.11 (OgnlRuntime) which is bundled with Struts2 may cause blank values be displayed when getter and setter of fields names are not same.

Comment: What is incorrect about it?

Comment: `is` is a getter prefix for boolean-s.

Comment: try `modelbean.isABooleanValue`.

Comment: `aBooleanValue` -> first letter to upper case -> add `id` -> `isABooleanValue` -> call method with that name -> win

Comment: yeah I got that @lxcky but in the above case what is happening in VS internally ??... usually when i access a field in jsp using VS i put the exact field name of the model object

Comment: @yeppe, to answer that question may I know what your variable name is? is it `isABooleanValue` or `aBooleanValue`?

Comment: variable name is isABooleanValue in the model but I can access that without using is in modelbean.aBooleanValue

Comment: What do you mean how? This is how the code is written that gets variables.

Comment: Can we get the real code snippets? Your setter won't work like that.

Comment: @AleksandrM As I understand you can't return anything from a method with `void` return type.

Comment: @lxcky Ahh you mean the return statement in the setter.

Comment: Still not sure what your question is about. Maybe this link will help you - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4462.

Comment: Your variable is `private` the getter will be called upon accessing it in jsp.

Comment: @AleksandrM, what his trying to ask is that why can we access the `isABooleanValue` variable using `aBooleanValue` when the variable name has a prefix `is`.

Comment: @yeppe You can read how it works better http://stackoverflow.com/a/28110630/573032

Comment: @yeppe It's basic Java question, even more OOP, because in other languages they also use a term of encapsulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned Aleksandr M the variable name has a `private` modifier. It hides the variable from Struts OGNL. When OGNL is evaluating an expression it's always looking for the object accessors available for the name.  Among them it uses one that better fit to get the value for the key being evaluated.

If a variable name has a `public` accessor it is using the name of this variable. And if it's a method accessor, then it calculates a name from the methd name.

For example if you have a method

```
public boolean isABooleanValue(){
     return isABooleanValue;
}
```

a names with `aBooleanValue` and `ABooleanValue` could be accessed by OGNL. It doesn't matter what it returns but it should be a `boolean` value.

It's not recommended to map such methods to an action, because unnecessary actions calls you may encounter via OGNL calls or during serialization.