# Correct format for getters/setters from Struts 2.3.32 onwards

Tags: struts2, migration, ognl

I was reading through this particular question (and the answer to it by Roman C). I came to know that the format of getters/setters have changed from Struts 2.3.32 and above:

[After having updated struts2 from 2.3.16 to 2.3.32（fix the S2-045), the JSP file can not resolve some Objects' fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779751/after-having-updated-struts2-from-2-3-16-to-2-3-32-fix-the-s2-045-the-jsp-file)

Can anybody please emphasize, what exactly are the format changes? (or point me towards the documentation that explains this in detail?)

I have boolean properties and getters/setters in my action class like these and I'm trying to *migrate from Struts 2.3.8 to 2.3.34*:

```
private boolean mlaCacheKeep;

public boolean isMlaCacheKeep() {
    return mlaCacheKeep;
}

public void setMlaCacheKeep(boolean mlaCacheKeep) {
    this.mlaCacheKeep = mlaCacheKeep;
}
```

After the migration, I notice, that for syntax such as these in my JSP...

```
<s:url id="newMLA" action="populateMlaForm">
    <s:param name="cacheKeep">%{mlaCacheKeep}</s:param>
</s:url>
```

...the value to `<s:param>` is not getting 'evaluated'. Instead of a `true` or a `false`, it's getting evaluated to something like this `%25%7BmlaCacheKeep%7D`

**Please note:** my property name doesn't start with only a single lower case character, but more than one lower case character.

Comment: try this <s:param name="cacheKeep" value="%{mlaCacheKeep}"/>

Comment: `<s:param name="cacheKeep">%{mlaCacheKeep}</s:param>` This is simply wrong. It doesn't work in either version. OGNL can be used in the tags.

Comment: @AleksandrM Do you mean this is syntactically wrong with respect to Struts 2.3.8?  (asking this, as the expression had been getting evaluated historically without any issues, while the app was on Struts 2.3.8, OGNL 3.0.6 and other dependent JARs). Thanks.

Comment: @want2learn I'll try out the syntax you suggested and post back about my results. Thanks.

Comment: @Tatha Yes. OGNL (`%{...}`) should work inside tag's attributes.

Comment: This particular syntax worked perfectly:
<s:param name="cacheKeep" value="%{mlaCacheKeep}"/> 
Thanks a lot, want2learn and Aleksandr M.

I wonder how the OGNL was getting evaluated without issues...even between tags, all these years for the app. Possibly, it's mandatory to mention OGNL as part of the "value" attribute only, from some particular Struts 2.3.x on wards?