# Struts 2 action's Boolean value is not binding from JSP after submitting the form

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

From JSP, Only the `Boolean` value is not binding into action's `Boolean` variable. Other all variable are getting binding fine.
`xBudgetFlag` is `Boolean` variable which is not binding.
Other all variables are binding.

Earlier from action to JSP also not worked, after added multiple getters for `xBudgetFlag` its working fine.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "request")
public class PaActions extends ActionSupport {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

.
.
.
private Long keyId;
private String taxUnit;
private Long surveyTypeId;
private String surveyType;
private Long accountId;
private String status;
private Boolean parentFlag;
private Boolean xBudgetFlag;

// all setter getter are here
// Tried with different ways of getter method thinking isxBudgetFlag() is working, but still all three getters are threre in action class
public Boolean getxBudgetFlag() {
    return xBudgetFlag;
}
public Boolean isXBudgetFlag() {
    return xBudgetFlag;
}
public Boolean isxBudgetFlag() {
    return xBudgetFlag;
}

public void setxBudgetFlag(Boolean xBudgetFlag) {
    this.xBudgetFlag = xBudgetFlag;
}

@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT)
public String save() {
    .
    .
    .
    
    System.out.println("----------isxBudget   --"+isxBudgetFlag()); // printing null
    System.out.println("---------- isXbudget  --"+isXBudgetFlag()); // printing null
    System.out.println("---------- GET XBUDGET --"+getxBudgetFlag());       // printing null
    System.out.println("---------- xBudgetFlag --"+xBudgetFlag);                    // printing null
    .
    .
    .
    return SUCCESS;
}
}
```

**in JSP `pa-edit.jsp`:**

```
<s:form id="PaActions" action="pa-submit" validate="true">
<s:token />
<s:hidden name="keyId" id="keyId"/>
.
.
.
<tr>
    <td class="formLabel"><label for="xBudgetFlag">X-Budget Flag</label></td>
    <td><s:checkbox property="xBudgetFlag" name="xBudgetFlag" /></td>
</tr>
.
.
.
<s:submit property="save" value="Save" id="save" />
</s:form>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<action name="pa-submit" class="/PaActions" method="save">
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">pa-display</param>
    <param name="key">${keyId}</param>
</result>
<result name="input" type="tiles">.pa.edit</result>
<result name="invalid.token" type="tiles">.pa.edit</result>
</action>
```

**`tiles.xml`:**

```
<definition name=".pa.edit" >
<put-attribute name="title" value="Project KKK" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="/pages/pa-edit.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="parentMenu" value="pa" cascade="true" />
</definition>
```

Comment: Version of Struts/OGNL?

Comment: Sorry for late response, version of struts is 2.3.16.3

Answer (score 2):

Try to use another setter name

```
public void setXBudgetFlag(Boolean xBudgetFlag) {
    this.xBudgetFlag = xBudgetFlag;
}
```

when the form is submitted the setter method is called to populate action class variables from the http parameters map. The correct setter method is determined to set the value and it depends on version of Struts/OGNL to find and invoke corresponding to a name the property accessor.

Since you have a property name with one lowercase letter first it won't be capitalized to calculate the name of the setter method, but in older versions the algorithm is different, so you have to either to add the setter method corresponding to the version of Struts/OGNL or rename the property to have at least two lowercase letters at first.

Also the `property` attribute doesn't exist on `<s:checkbox>` tag, use the `name` attribute.

So change

```jsp
<td><s:checkbox property="xBudgetFlag" name="xBudgetFlag" /></td>
```

to

```jsp
<td><s:checkbox name="xBudgetFlag" /></td>
```

Comment: You are really awesome.. it worked  with setXBudgetFlag(Boolean xBudgetFlat)... Still I wonder why it's not worked with setxBudgetFlag.. (small x) which is generated by eclipse.. Whatever.. Thank you

Comment: The version of OGNL used with the Struts 2.3.16 has a legacy algorithm to determine a method accessor as I mentioned in this answer. You can learn from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28110630/573032) answer to know more about property accessors.